# trying to send info trouhg headers with post

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, request-headers

I'm making a Rest Api with Node.js, but I have no idea of how to put information on headers and receive it in another endpoint, in this case, I want to send the token signed in headers to get it in another endpoint with a require.headers

So, What's the method I should use? and if you have an explanation is better.

```
  const { Router } = require("express");
    const router = Router();
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const authmiddleware = require('../Middlewares/auth.middleware')
    
    router.get("/kiral/jwt", (req, res) => {
        const token = jwt.sign({
            data: "informacion importante"
        }, 'seed', {expiresIn: '1h' });
    
      res.json({
        message: "Hello endpoint jwt",
        token
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send the token information in the response headers you do something like this

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const router = Router();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const authmiddleware = require('../Middlewares/auth.middleware')

router.get("/kiral/jwt", (req, res) => {
    const token = jwt.sign({
        data: "informacion importante"
    }, 'seed', {expiresIn: '1h' });
  res.header('token', token); // this will be sent in response headers 
  res.json({
    message: "Hello endpoint jwt",
    token
  });
});
```